# I installed Grub on Windows 10, how do i install themes?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, themes

I managed to install Ubuntu on an external HDD and Grub alongside Windows boot manager.

I also managed to solve the issue which launches directly into Grub Rescue, if Ubuntu HDD is unplugged. It happily launches to the grub menu and when I boot from there, it won't boot ubuntu, just like I expected and wanted. And booting from Windows is also no problem either. (That is because I've added a custom grub.cfg, then copied and pasted ubuntu's grub.cfg)

But, I wanted to ask one thing or two: How do I install themes for it? I've tried with Grub Customizer yet it didn't work...

Also When Secure Boot is on, I can't boot into Grub (how do I enter grub without disabling secure boot? As I did make a partition for Fat32 EFI and \Boot for Ubuntu on my external HDD).

My primary grub is installed on the system partition (which is called M: which only can be accessed as an administrator command line), which is located in nvme0n1p1 (p1 means the first partition). The Grub is located: M:\efi\grub, where all of it is installed: Themes, .efi, etc.

I used [this website](https://www.aioboot.com/en/install-grub2-from-windows/) to install grub on my windows system partition.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how and why you installed GRUB "from Windows".  GRUB is installed with Ubuntu even when Ubuntu is the only operating system. Many people will tell you that trying to customize GRUB with themes is a very bad idea because GRUB is an essential and "low-level" utility that is necessary to boot Ubuntu. You see it for all of 5 seconds and it's just not worth the risk for something so trite.  But this being Linux, just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*. GRUB customizer is a plague IMO

Comment: Umm i downloaded grub by searching grub 2.04 for windows, at first after you installed your grub on windows boot loader and added it to the boot menu, you will enter grub rescue, because you don't have grub.cfg on your grub file. Adding that and voila, everything works.

Comment: i don't think grub customizer is a bad idea, having a nice UI in the boot menu is something I really wanted, but its annoying to always plug in external harddrive and boot into grub from there.

Comment: I can't help you about the problem you asked us but you says is this possible to use grub without disabling secure boot and I think by the way you use Ubuntu, it was not possible because I duel-boot Ubuntu along side of windows and I didn't disable secure boot and fast boot because so much of OS is supporting secure boot and even fast boot like Ubuntu but I think because you installed grub on windows (from windows) it was not possible to use it without disabling secure boot

Comment: I still don't understand **why** you installed GRUB from Windows? GRUB was already installed if Ubuntu was installed.  Are you able to boot both operating systems?  When you boot Ubuntu from the GRUB you installed for Windows, are you certain that you aren't getting GRUB twice?  This could slow your boot and Ubuntu's GRUB might not actually be visible, based on your description of your actions

Comment: i did disable secure boot, Also i installed grub on my external HDD, and if i reboot my pc i will get into grub rescue if i dont plug my HDD, and i dont want that. And when i set windows boot as primary boot AND plug the HDD i wont have the grub menu unless i have to enter bios, which is tedius

Answer (score 0):

In the `Grub` folder there is a folder called `themes`. You can copy your downloaded theme(s) for Grub to that map. Now you have three ways to get where you want to be.

1. Use Grub-customizer in Ubuntu to add the theme. Use the third tab `display options`.
2. Customize your `grub.conf` configuration file directly. In my case this is:
   [[image: grub.conf]
   This will be deleted when you upgrade your grub.conf ( after for instance you update your kernel and do `sudo update-grub` afterwards.
3. You change your `05_debian_theme` file. ( doesn't change after update-grub ). This file is located in `etc/grub.d`. Look at the line-numbers!
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

I have to do these as pictures because if I do it as code the format is corrupted.

In my example I used debian theme with my own background picture. The background picture is always called background.png

Using grub-customizer is the easiest way. Make backup first!!!